# How do I merge two catalogs with Extensis Portfolio 9?

Tags: organizer-software, cataloging

In previous versions of Portfolio, I could open multiple catalogs in tabs in the same window and then do select all and drag items from one tab to another. But in Portfolio 9, once connected to a catalog on a server, I don't seem to be able to open any `.fdb` catalogs alongside.

When I double-click on an `.fdb` file, it just activates the Portfolio Client window without any changes to the tab bar. And if I can have only one catalog open at a time, why even have the tab bar?

But my primary question is how does one merge two catalogs with Portfolio 9, via tabs or using some other way?